# HTML5 page logging with MySql database in Node.js with socket.io

Tags: mysql, html, node.js, socket.io

I tried the database login with HTML5+MySQL+Node.js+socket.io but failed. Please help.
I want to login from HTML5 page to MySQL database with Node.js and socket.io

I have a HTML5 page with 2 text box user name and password and a LogIn button.
user want to login from HTML5 page with user/password send to server and the server receive the user/password and validate with mysql database and return the result.

**My Code:
server_test.js**

```
var io = require('C:/Program Files (x86)/nodejs/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io');
var socket = io.listen(8124);
socket.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('login', function(data, usr, pass){
        var mysql = require('mysql');
        var TEST_DATABASE = 'employee';
        var TEST_TABLE = 'tblusers';
        var client = mysql.createClient({
          user: 'root',
          password: 'secret10',
        });

        client.query('USE '+TEST_DATABASE);

        client.query(
          'SELECT name FROM '+TEST_TABLE+' WHERE user = '+usr+' AND password = '+pass,
          function selectCb(err, results) {
            if (err) {
              throw err;
            }
            //Emit a message to client
            socket.emit('retuLogIn',{username: results[0]['name']});
            client.end();
          }
        );
    });
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log('Server has disconnected');
        });
});
```

**client_test.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <title>WebSocket Client Demo [socket.io]</title>
    <script src="/json.js"></script> <!-- for ie -->
    <script src="http://localhost:8124/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    function connect() {

        try
        {
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8124/');
            socket.on("connect",function(){
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML ="Browser has connected to the app server";
            });
            socket.on('login', function (data, document.getElementById('txtUser').value, document.getElementById('txtPass').value) {
                //alert(data.hello);
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Welcome '+data.username;
            });
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = err.message;
        }
    }
    </script>
    <body>
        <h1>WebSocket Client Demo</h1>
        <div><p id="status">Enter user and password to Log-In</p></div>
        <label>User :</label>
        <input id="txtUser" type="text" maxlength="10" />
        <label>Password :</label>
        <input id="txtPass" type="text" maxlength="10" />
        <button id="connect" onClick='connect()'/>Log-In</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note :
I am tried with above mention code but no success. I was tried to send the userid/password to server from client with socket.send('abcd', 'ab12'). able to send but can't receive in server.

Please help me how to solve this issue. I am using MySQL database.

As an update, when I apply Joel's suggestions, I still see an error when I try to run app.js in Node.js:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\app.js"    info  - socket.io started

C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\app.js:6
    var client = mysql.createConnection({
                       ^ TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'createConnection'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\app.js:6:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function._load (module.js:312:12)
    at module.js:487:10
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:238:9)

C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs>
```

What could be wrong with this now?

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the script as I needed something similar, here you go:

app.js:

```
    var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
      , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)
      , fs = require('fs')
      , mysql = require('mysql')

    var client = mysql.createConnection({
              host: 'localhost',
              user: 'root',
              password: '',
    });

    client.connect();

    app.listen(3232);

    function handler (req, res) {
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
      function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          res.writeHead(500);
          return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }

        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
      });
    }

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('login', function(usr, pass){
            var TEST_DATABASE = 'mysqltest';
            var TEST_TABLE = 'users';

            client.query('USE '+TEST_DATABASE);

            client.query('SELECT name FROM '+TEST_TABLE+' WHERE user = "'+usr+'" AND password = "'+pass+'"', function(err, results) {
              if (err) throw err;
              console.log(results[0]); // [{1: 1}]
              socket.emit('retuLogIn',results[0]['name']);
            });

        });
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){
            console.log('Server has disconnected');
        });
    });
```

And the index.html:

```
<html>
    <title>WebSocket Client Demo [socket.io]</title>
    <script src="http://localhost:3232/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
    function connect() {

        try
        {
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3232/');
            socket.on("connect",function(){
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML ="Browser has connected to the app server";
                socket.emit('login', document.getElementById('txtUser').value, document.getElementById('txtPass').value);

            });
            socket.on('retuLogIn', function (data) {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Welcome '+data;
            });
        }
        catch(err)
        {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = err.message;
        }
    }
    </script>
    <body>
        <h1>WebSocket Client Demo</h1>
        <div><p id="status">Enter user and password to Log-In</p></div>
        <label>User :</label>
        <input id="txtUser" type="text" maxlength="10" />
        <label>Password :</label>
        <input id="txtPass" type="text" maxlength="10" />
        <button id="connect" onClick='connect()'/>Log-In</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

You need to change stuff like mysql database name, username, password and probaly the ports if needed.

I used node.js, socket.io and node-mysql

Comment: Joel, I tried with your code but no success. Can you please see where am I wrong.I am getting error like : C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\app.js" info - socket.io started C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\app.js:6 var client = mysql.createConnection({ ^ TypeError: Object # has no method 'createConnection' at Object. (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\app.js:6:24) at Module._compile (module.js:449:26) at Object..js (module.js:467:10) at Module.load (module.js:356:32) at Function._load (module.js:312:12) at module.js:487:10 at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:238:9)

Answer (score 0):

Chandan Dey you are missing

```
mysql = require('mysql')
```

in your code,
cheers